# Wordpress Page ID not Post ID

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there any way to get ID of the current page which shows posts in loop? I need to get this ID in header.php.

```
<?php
     $query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'portfolio') );
     while ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
          $query->the_post(); 
 ?>                           
 //here I added posts
 <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where you want to get this ID. If you are trying to get it on the page that you have set to show posts (ie, a page set as your "blog"), you need to use:

```
$page_id = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );
```

If you want to get this on any other page and you're using a custom query, you can get this (before your custom loop) using:

```
global $post;
$page_id = $post->ID;
```

Because you're using WP_Query and `the_post()`, you'll want to reset the post data after your custom loop with `wp_reset_postdata();` to use template tags again. I suspect that's where your problem is - you're hijacking the template tags with your custom loop and not resetting them.

Comment: This is what I want to achieve, but if I reset query and use global variable, I only get the ID of the first post, not the ID of the page with this posts.

Comment: Can you post more of your code? If you're on a standard page and request the global $post variable before any custom query, you'll get the page id. ($post->ID is the page id in this case)

Comment: I realized that if I run your code using default permalinks, it works perfectly. But how is it possible to achieve that using custom permalinks of structure /localhost/web/%postname%/ ?

Comment: This will work with any permalinks. If not, something is hijacking your $post before you call the code. You'll need to pinpoint where that's happening - perhaps in a theme function or plugin that never resets the $post variable after a custom query. To see it in action, switch to the default theme, disable all plugins, and put this code in header.php. You'll see it print out the page id on every page, with or without custom permalinks.

Comment: Tried as you mentioned, but the same result even if I use default permalink with ID, so it won't be hijacking $post in my code. Can it be influenced by using localhost?

Comment: You're visiting a single Page, right? You're not trying to do this on a category, tag, or archive "page" but an actual Page you created in the Dashboard?

Comment: So it is my big mistake. Because I created my first own theme an it do not support custom menu, I created page with slug portfolio. Also custom post type has defined slug portfolio, so if I am right it uses archive-portfolio.php. Also I have page Blog, but in reading's settings I set Page for posts : Blog, so it will use template index.php. And now I know that I will never get the ID of this generated pages, am I right? I can't do it like set page template in page options, because then I would need new page for each category. Thank you for your time.

Comment: That's correct - the archive "pages" (like archive-portfolio.php) don't have page IDs. Glad we got to the bottom of it!

Comment: Thank you a lot, I own you a favor. If you will need something I make Windows, Windows Phone apps and websites so we can stay in touch, my e-mail is martin.bojnansky@gmail.com.

Answer (score 0):

The get_the_ID() method is probably what you need:

```
 <?php get_the_ID(); ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID

Comment: If I use  <?php get_the_ID(); ?>  outside of the loop, no matter if it is before or after, I get the ID of the last post, not the ID of the page where posts are.

Comment: Why use it outside of the loop?

Comment: Each page has a color custom field and color of the page depends on this value. So I don't want to get the ID of the posts which I am showing on this page, but ID of the page which shows posts.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but you wouldn't need to know the ID of the page to be able to call a custom field.

Comment: But if I call function to get custom-field value without an ID, I will get custom field of post inside a loop, not custom-field value of the page which have this loop.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve? (an image may help?) it sounds like you may not be approaching it the right way.

Comment: Each page has custom field color and it's color. I am trying to change the color of the menu which is called in header.php. See image for more: http://1drv.ms/ZB0K1W

Answer (score 0):

Try `get_queried_object()`. It returns the `WP_Post` object which is from the queried page. From there you can get the `id` using

```php
get_queried_object()->ID.
```