# Wordpress get page id not post id

Tags: wordpress

How to get page id not post id?

I'm tried these, but always get post id.

```
global $wp_query;
print $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();

global $post;
print $post->ID;

$wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26450720/wordpress-page-id-not-post-id) questions also not resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sevi WordPress stores page as a post, and you can get requested page id by 
`<?php get_the_ID(); ?>`

Answer (score 2):

Try using this outside the Loop.

```
global $post;
print $post->ID;
```